# Windows 7 Can't uninstall Microsoft Security Essentials

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, ms-security-essentials

to describe the problem as simple as possible, the company edition of Microsoft's Security Essentials called "System Center Endpoint Protection" is installed on my private computer and despite me being the administrator of the machine I'm not able to uninstall it.

If I select the according entry in the "Program & Features" dialog the uninstall button disappears, if I click on any other entry the button reappears and I can uninstall any software I want.
Also I'm not able to stop the according "Microsoft Antimalware Service". If I open it in the services.msc dialog all the components are disabled.
I found two fixits from Microsoft which sounded promising but unfortunately didn't solve the problem.

So my question is, how do I get rid of this piece of software.

Thanks Simon

Comment: Do you have the capability of rolling back the system from before MSE was installed?

Comment: try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2483120/en-us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of a sudden I managed to solve the problem in a surprisingly easy way.

I started searching the registry for "System Center 2012", willing to delete every single entry by hand as no other tip and even some Microsoft FixIts didn't help and came across this entry:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\Setup.exe" /x
```

Just executed it and voilà problem solved :-)